# Get instant update of changing image width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an image (one letter) displayed. The image can be changed by pressing on other letter buttons (change_letter function). Each letter has different width (from 18px for "I" to 35px for "W"). I want to center all letters inside the div and use

```
margin-left:-width/2+"px"
```

for that. However, the width value that I get, is always that of a previous image. So, after I change letter from "W" (35px) to "I" (18px), "I" gets margin-left: -17.5px (that of W's), instead of -9px.

I wonder how to instantly get width of the new image.

```
change_letter: function(e) {
    var txt = $(e.target).text().toLowerCase();

    if (this.typeFace !==2) {
        $('#customlogo_layer2').attr('src',function(_,old_src){
        return old_src.replace(/_(\w)_/g,'_'+txt+'_');
        });

        $('#customlogo_layer3').attr('src',function(_,old_src){
        return old_src.replace(/_(\w)_/g,'_'+txt+'_');
        });

        var layer2img = document.getElementById('customlogo_layer2'); 
        var layer2width = layer2img.clientWidth;
        var layer3img = document.getElementById('customlogo_layer3'); 
        var layer3width = layer3img.clientWidth;

        $('#customlogo_layer2').css({"margin-left":-layer2width/2+"px","margin-right":-layer2width/2+"px"});
        $('#customlogo_layer3').css({"display":"block","margin-left":-layer3width/2+"px","margin-right":-layer3width/2+"px"});
        }
    else
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think when you get the image width the image is not loaded yet

try this :

```
   $('#customlogo_layer2').load(function(){

      var layerWidth = $(this)[0].clientWidth;

      $(this).css({"margin-left":-layerWidth/2+"px","margin-right":-layerWidth/2+"px"});

   })

   $('#customlogo_layer3').load(function(){

      var layerWidth = $(this)[0].clientWidth;

      $(this).css({"display":"block","margin-left":-layerWidth/2+"px","margin-right":-layerWidth/2+"px"});

   }) 

   $('#customlogo_layer2').attr('src',function(_,old_src){
    return old_src.replace(/_(\w)_/g,'_'+txt+'_');
    });

    $('#customlogo_layer3').attr('src',function(_,old_src){
    return old_src.replace(/_(\w)_/g,'_'+txt+'_');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the src of an image with jQuery by adding random number in the query

```
$(imageobj).attr('src', $(imageobj)
       .attr('src') + '?' + Math.random() );
```